# How To Enable Location Services In C#?

Tags: c#, geolocation, console-application, geocoding

I want to create a simple **Console Application**, which will retrieve me the Coordinates of the computer. I don't really know how to enable the location services on the computer ..
So far, my code looks like this:

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
GeoCoordinate CurrentCoordinate = watcher.Position.Location;
if (CurrentCoordinate.IsUnknown)
{
    Console.WriteLine("At this time, your coordinates are unknown..\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to force the program to find your coordinates?\n(Y = yes, All Any Other Key = no)");
    ConsoleKeyInfo KPress = Console.ReadKey(false);
    if (KPress.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
    {
        /*
        Enabling The Location Services & Find The User's Location Coordinates
        */

        GeoCoordinate NewCoord = ReFindCoordinates(watcher);

        Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + NewCoord.Latitude);
        Console.WriteLine("Longtitude: " + NewCoord.Longitude);
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + CurrentCoordinate.Latitude);
    Console.WriteLine("Longtitude: " + CurrentCoordinate.Longitude);
}
```

Does anybody know how to enable this services via C#? I will be glad to get some help..
Thank you.

Comment: What hardware are you attending to use?

Comment: @Softwarehuset Right Now, i'm using a TOSHIBA leptop(SATELLITE L755), but basically I want the software to be possible to use in a different computers..

Comment: I am missing something. do you have GPS antenna on your laptop ? How does the GeoCoordinateWatcher class suppose to get the data on your current location when you execture trystart ?

Comment: @ilansch - Thank you for your reply.
I don't have GPS antenna, but I still can get(manually) my location via this link, for example(http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation).. so if I don't have any GPS antenna, how this site can still find my exact location?

Comment: I dont know how this class is working, how does the coordinate received, Does a laptop has location service ? is it enabled ? how does the location service works.. these are open questions, i see this is the right use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438273/return-the-location-data-from-geocoordinatewatcher-statuschanged-event-in-window

Answer (score 0):

Grab geolocation from the web?

```
internal GeoLoc GetMyGeoLocation()
{
try
{
    //create a request to geoiptool.com
    var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://geoiptool.com/data.php")) as HttpWebRequest;


if (request != null)
{
    //set the request user agent
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

    //get the response
    using (var webResponse = (request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse))
        if (webResponse != null)
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {

                //get the XML document
                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(reader);

                //now we parse the XML document
                var nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("marker");

                Guard.AssertCondition(nodes.Count > 0,"nodes",new object());
                //make sure we have nodes before looping
                //if (nodes.Count > 0)
                //{
                    //grab the first response
                    var marker = nodes[0] as XmlElement;

                    Guard.AssertNotNull(marker, "marker");

                    var _geoLoc = new GeoLoc();
                    //get the data and return it
                    _geoLoc.City = marker.GetAttribute("city");
                    _geoLoc.Country = marker.GetAttribute("country");
                    _geoLoc.Code = marker.GetAttribute("code");
                    _geoLoc.Host = marker.GetAttribute("host");
                    _geoLoc.Ip = marker.GetAttribute("ip");
                    _geoLoc.Latitude = marker.GetAttribute("lat");
                    _geoLoc.Lognitude = marker.GetAttribute("lng");
                    _geoLoc.State = GetMyState(_geoLoc.Latitude, _geoLoc.Lognitude);

                    return _geoLoc;
                //}
            }
       }

    // this code would only be reached if something went wrong 
    // no "marker" node perhaps?
    return new GeoLoc();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
}
```

[Get IP geolocation using C# & WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117294/get-ip-geolocation-using-c-sharp-wpf)

Comment: That's not reliable. Right now, a web site I use believes that I'm in New Jersey, in the USA, but I'm over 3,000 miles away from there.

Comment: the same case for me, this is giving me some other place.. 
for example, this html example returning me the real position:http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the Bing Maps API and get your location from their web services?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

Comment: if i'm using this location API, it returns me an error: "Access was denied. You may have entered your credentials incorrectly, or you might not have access to the requested resource or operation."

Comment: You probably need to create a developer account and get an API Key: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx

1. Go to the Bing Maps Dev Center at https://www.bingmapsportal.com/.
If you have a Bing Maps account, sign in with the Microsoft account that you used to create the account or create a new one. For new accounts, follow the instructions in Creating a Bing Maps Account.
2. Select Keys under My Account.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [GeoCoordinateWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher(v=vs.100).aspx) class, there is some delay in retrieving the location. So you can hook to the **watcher_PositionChanged** event and get teh location from there. Hope this helps

```
 _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
 _watcher.TryStart(true, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
 _watcher.PositionChanged += watcher_PositionChanged;

 void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        if (e.Position.Location != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}",
                e.Position.Location.Latitude,
                e.Position.Location.Longitude);
            _watcher.Stop();
        }
    }
```